# log4net.ext.json - DateTime formatting

Tags: log4net-ext-json

DateTime formatting in log4net.ext.json appears to be inconsistent,
sometimes I get standard json style dates

> "CreatedDateTimeUtc": "/Date(1496846467024)/"

sometimes

> "PublishedAt": "2017-06-07T14:41:06.7098470",

is there a way I can specify which format I'd like? or is it dependent on a property on the DateTime?

what I'd really like is the format it uses for the log date

> "date": "2017-06-07T15:41:07.0244105+01:00",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the case in recent 2.0.8 release. See the [test case for SerializeDateTime](https://github.com/BrightOpen/log4net.Ext.Json/blob/master/log4net.Ext.Json.Xunit/ObjectRenderer/Simple.cs).